# How to login in basecamp using google login android

Tags: android, authentication, integration, basecamp

What will i do.

1. i had call a url(From github scratch point 1( [Github link](https://github.com/basecamp/api/blob/master/sections/authentication.md#oauth-2-from-scratch) )in Android webview1.  when get a verification code from webview url, i will close webview1.
2. got the verification code and call a task for access token,
3. successfully get token and then call API for user details.
4. i got whole details successfully in json format.
5. its done basecamp login :)

But the issue is when i try to login with the google inside basecamp

1. click to login with google.
2. redirect to google login screen in webview2 and i enter email and password.
3. After that i will see the google login webview2 close on successful login.
4. Then i see the option for basecamp2,basecamp3 etc.. in webview1. //*This will work only in below kitkat version, after 5.0 it will nothing to show login details. just show a basecamp login screen. means ignoring point 5 and 6.*
5. if i click on basecamp 2 they instructed that install basecamp android app
6. if i click on basecamp 3 they says me that you are using old browser etc....

**Question**:
*How can i get the basecamp identity and user email address after this process.*

[image]

**Need Suggestions:** what basecamp will do if i inject a javascript and hide google button when user open basecamp login screen?